# Thinkster Example: Passing data from model into directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a question about one part in a Thinkster example. I think my lack of understanding stems from weaker Javascript knowledge, and not understanding some fundamental of AngularJS. I've been self-teaching since December, learning the basics of JavaScript and now Angular. If you could explain it (like I'm 5) that'd be greatly appreciated!
[Thinkster Page](https://thinkster.io/egghead/understanding-isolate-scope)

App.js

```
app.controller("ChoreCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.logChore = function(chore){
    alert(chore + " is done!");
  };
});

app.directive("kid", function() {
   return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
    done: "&"
   },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="chore">' +
    //This is the part I'm slightly confused about

      '{{chore}}' +
      '<div class="button" ng-click="done({chore: chore})">I\'m done</div>'
  };
});
```

HTML

```
    <div ng-app="choreApp">
      <div ng-controller="ChoreCtrl">
        <kid done="logChore(chore)"></kid>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How does {chore:chore} work? Thinkster states the following:

> The {chore:chore} syntax maps the chore from the model we made in the <input> to be passed to the logChore function when we said 'done="logChore(chore)"' (in the kid directive)

My thoughts are:

1. Click invokes "done", which invokes "logChore(chore)" based off HTML attribute
2. I'm guessing `"{chore:chore}"`, in App.js is passed into logChore, so in a sense it's logChore(chore:chore)?

Why can't I just have `ng-click=(done(chore))`? What exactly is happening with the `{chore:chore}`? It may be clear I have no idea what is going on haha.

Much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `&` operator, see here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

It says:

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name.

So basically, that accesses the `chore` property of the parent scope, otherwise we'd be in the directive's isolate scope which doesn't have the `chore` property.

Also, see his explanation here: https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am

See if this code clarifies it a bit - I've modified the property names so that now we have `innerChore`, `outerChore` and `param` to avoid the name confusion:

```js
var app = angular.module('choreApp', []);

app.controller("ChoreCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.logChore = function(param){
    alert(param + " is done!");
  };
});

app.directive("kid", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        done: "&"
      },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="innerChore">' +
      '{{innerChore}}' +
      '<div class="button" ng-click="done({outerChore: innerChore})">I\'m done</div>'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="choreApp">
  <div ng-controller="ChoreCtrl">
    <kid done="logChore(outerChore)"></kid>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the relation in `{outerChore: innerChore}`.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around - it provides a way for the outer scope to access the chore value of the inner (isolate) scope?

Comment: @GregL seems like no. This feature wasn't there when I last used angular (I think), so I had to play around a bit. See my code, did I properly name the chore properties or you think it should be the other way round?

Comment: I think your new version is correct. Though perhaps `outerChore` should be called `localChore` instead, since it is not on the outer scope, it is just a local variable that needs a value supplied by the directive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it. You guys do a great job of answering questions. It would've taken me hours to figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the `done` attribute expression says: `logChore(chore)`. This is evaluated against the `$scope` for the `ChoreCtrl` (that means that variable and function names have to be on that scope object). Okay, so let's look at what variables and functions we are referring to: `logChore()` and `chore`. `logChore()` makes sense, that is an explicit function property on the `$scope`. But where is `chore` on the `$scope` object? Nowhere!

Now, when you call `.done()` in the directive's `link()` function, you are passing in a *locals map*, which specifies values for variables that will overwrite any on the `$scope`. In this case, `{chore: chore}` means "use the `chore` object on the directive's isolated scope as the value for the `chore` variable (if there is one) in the expression specified for the `done` attribute. Suddenly, we know what `chore` is in the `logChore(chore)` expression, which we didn't before.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Greg, thanks for the answer! Really appreciate the time the community puts in to answering these questions.